# Magento2: How to validate form and display error message below input field

Tags: magento2, forms, validation, form-validation, contact-form

In magento 1.x we use the following code to validate Magento forms:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var myForm= new VarienForm('contactstore', true);
</script>
```

I am using this code from the magento 2 contact form:

```
<div class="field email required">
  <label class="label" for="email"><span>Email</span></label>
    <div class="control">
      <input name="email" id="email" title="Email" value="" class="input-text" type="email" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}" aria-required="true">
    </div>
</div>
```

My question is: how do I validate a custom form in Magento 2?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to do add **data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'** inside form declaration as following:

```
<form class="form contact"
      action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getFormAction(); ?>"
      id="contact-form"
      method="post"
      data-hasrequired="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('* Required Fields') ?>"
      data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>
```

[Click here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Contact/view/frontend/templates/form.phtml)

Comment: I can add and remove fields from the JS validation. I removed the name fields from the registration form, but back-end still requires them, and I don't know where to find the settings! :-O

Comment: I want display error and custom message when blur input. Please help me?

Comment: For a custom checkbox i want to please this message "This is a required field" if checkbox is not checked.

Answer (score 3):

**Form Validation can be applied in three ways:**

1)

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "#custom-form": {
    "validation": {}
    }
}
</script>
```

2)

```
<form data-mage-init='{"validation": {}}' 
class="form" id="custom-form" method="post" autocomplete="off">
```

3)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require([
  'jquery',
  'mage/mage'
], function($){

var dataForm = $('#custom-form');
dataForm.mage('validation', {});
});
</script>
```

Further you may need validation classed from the below list.
You just need to add css class for the rule to apply.

> min_text_length
>
> max_text_length
>
> max-words
>   min-words
>
> range-words
>
> letters-with-basic-punc
>
> alphanumeric
>
> letters-only
>
> no-whitespace

**See more in this link: http://blog.i13websolution.com/magento-2-validation-rules/**

Comment: Hi Ahmad 


Thanks for the solution, the error message div coming below to the input box at newsletter subscribe section in footer. how to make it above the input box.

Answer (score 3):

Form ID: #custom-register-form

Before Submit the form Check the validation

To Check All Fields & Display Error:

```
$('#custom-register-form').on('submit', function (event) {
var dataForm = jQuery('#custom-register-form');
if(dataForm.validation('isValid') === false){
    return false;
}});
```

To Single Fields & Display Error:

```
$("#custom-register-form input").bind('keyup focusout autocompletechange change', function (){$(this).valid();});
```